# Combining commands and events

Tags: discord.py

I am building a discord bot that I want to be able to interact both with commands and emojis. Here is the code so far:

```
import os
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

client = discord.Client()

@bot.command(name='repeat', help='help me to understand bots')
async def test(ctx, *args):
    for arg in args:
        await ctx.send(arg)


@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    print("someone reacted to something")
    print(payload)


bot.run(TOKEN)
client.run(TOKEN)
```

My intuition is that the last two lines are where this goes wrong, although I don't understand the run(TOKEN) feature to have a good understanding of why this happens, or how to fix it.

Comment: Using `bot = commands.Bot()` includes both commands and events. Remove the `client` stuff and rename `@client.event` to `@bot.event`, then you should be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To further develop this you need to fully understand what you've done and have a plan for what you want to do.  I will first direct you to [the discord python documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/) Where you can see everything discord.py has to offer.  This should probably be your first stop when you have questions.

I see you have `import discord` and `from discord.ext import commands`... discord.py has two ways to approach a bot, which you have:

`client = discord.Client()` hails from `import discord`, and
`bot = commands.Bot()` hails from `import discord.ext`.

You need to choose whether to use `discord.Client()` or `discord.Bot()` because the use cases are entirely different.  I suggest the latter, as it will allow your bot to do more, in a cleaner fashion.

Your next step would be to change any @ decorators to whichever variable you choose and keep that consistent throughout your code.  Then, you need to remove whichever `.run(TOKEN)` you won't use. So, if I were you, I would read the documentation which I linked to you so you understand more than a YouTube tutorial would teach.

As for a revision to your code, it would look like this:

```py
import os
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@bot.command(name='repeat', help='help me to understand bots')
async def test(ctx, *args):
    for arg in args:
        await ctx.send(arg)

@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    print("someone reacted to something")
    print(payload)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I struggled to find the relevant parts of the documentation for bots/clients. Is it this https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot#bot ?

Comment: It seems like bot.event takes precedence over bot.command. Once I have bot.events, no commands are executed any more. You need `await bot.process_commands(payload)` after `print(payload)`